# When I parse json it turns everything into nil

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift4, xcode9

When I call my php file with swift and retrieve json it returns in bytes

http://jacobwebb.xyz/app.php - Link I am using to display data

Now I think everything is fine when i get it because it returns in output Optional(275 bytes) but when I try to parse the data and then print again everything turns back nil as you can see below I take 2 different json objects and try to run it then it returns nil.

Sorry If this might be simple I am learning how to code in swift.

Name: nil, Address: nil, Latitude: nil, Longitude: nil, id: nil, Info: nil, time: nil

Name: nil, Address: nil, Latitude: nil, Longitude: nil, id: nil, Info: nil, time: nil

Here is my viewController.swift

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  dropDeals
//
//  Created by jacob webb on 9/23/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 jacob webb. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    var locTimer = Timer()
    var found = false
    var data = Data()
    let urlPath: String = "http://jacobwebb.xyz/app.php"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        //Start event
        locTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.getJsonFromUrl), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        self.getJsonFromUrl()
    }
    @objc func getJsonFromUrl(){

        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to download data")
            }else {
                print("Data downloaded")
                print(data)
                self.parseJSON(data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {

        var jsonResult = NSArray()

        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)

        }

        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        let locations = NSMutableArray()

        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
        {

            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            let location = LocationModel()

            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if let name = jsonElement["Name"] as? String,
                let address = jsonElement["Address"] as? String,
                let latitude = jsonElement["Latitude"] as? String,
                let longitude = jsonElement["Longitude"] as? String,
                let id = jsonElement["id"] as? Int,
                let info = jsonElement["info"] as? String,
                let time = jsonElement["time"] as? Int {
                location.name = name
                location.address = address
                location.latitude = latitude
                location.longitude = longitude
                location.id = id
                location.info = info
                location.time = time
            }

            locations.add(location)
            print(location)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

        })
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if found == false {
            let location = locations[0]
            let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.04, 0.04)
            let coord:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
            let currentRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coord, span)
            map.setRegion(currentRegion, animated: true)
            self.map.showsUserLocation = true
            found = true
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my LocationModel object

```
//
//  LocationModel.swift
//  dropDeals
//
//  Created by jacob webb on 9/24/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 jacob webb. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

class LocationModel: NSObject {

    //properties

    var name: String?
    var address: String?
    var latitude: String?
    var longitude: String?
    var id: Int?
    var info: String?
    var time: Int?

    //empty constructor

    override init()
    {

    }

    //construct with @name, @address, @latitude, and @longitude parameters

    init(name: String, address: String, latitude: String, longitude: String, id: Int, info: String, time: Int) {

        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.id = id
        self.info = info
        self.time = time
    }


    //prints object's current state

    override var description: String {
        return "Name: \(name), Address: \(address), Latitude: \(latitude), Longitude: \(longitude), id: \(id), Info: \(info), time: \(time)"

    }


}
```

Comment: All parameter are String type.

Comment: Why are you using NSDictionary and not the native Swift types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. Replace your big `if let` comma-list with simple `let`:

```
let name = jsonElement["Name"] as? String
let address = jsonElement["Address"] as? String
let latitude = jsonElement["Latitude"] as? String
let longitude = jsonElement["Longitude"] as? String
let id = jsonElement["id"] as? Int
let info = jsonElement["info"] as? String
let time = jsonElement["time"] as? Int
location.name = name
location.address = address
location.latitude = latitude
location.longitude = longitude
location.id = id
location.info = info
location.time = time
```

The way you *were* doing it, if just *one* of them is `nil`, they all end up `nil`. That isn't what you want.

And some of them *are* `nil`, because you are saying `as? Int`, which always fails; everything in the JSON dictionary is a String. If you want to make an Int out of that, you must *coerce* to an Int; you cannot simply *cast* to an Int and make it so. For example, you might say:

```
let id : Int? = {
    if let id = jsonElement["id"] as? String {
        return Int(id)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}()
```

And similarly for `time`.

---

However, I strongly suggest that you learn Swift 4, where this kind of thing is basically trivial. You've designed your model poorly, so some extra preparation is needed:

```
struct LocationModel : Decodable {
    var name: String?
    var address: String?
    var latitude: String?
    var longitude: String?
    var id: Int?
    var info: String?
    var time: Int?
    enum Keys : String, CodingKey {
        case name = "Name"
        case address = "Address"
        case latitude = "Latitude"
        case longitude = "Longitude"
        case id
        case info
        case time
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let con = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Keys.self)
        self.name = try con.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.address = try con.decode(String.self, forKey: .address)
        self.latitude = try con.decode(String.self, forKey: .latitude)
        self.longitude = try con.decode(String.self, forKey: .longitude)
        self.id = Int(try con.decode(String.self, forKey: .id))
        self.info = try con.decode(String.self, forKey: .info)
        self.time = Int(try con.decode(String.self, forKey: .time))
    }
}
```

After that, however, it's really simple. Here's the test string:

```
let s = """
[{"Name":"test1","Address":"2206 ne parvin rd","Latitude":"39.172196","Longitude":"-94.549035","id":"1","info":"Special Going On","time":"1"},{"Name":"test2","Address":"somewhere","Latitude":"39.171816","Longitude":"-94.548157","id":"2","info":"Special INN Deal","time":"1"}]
"""
let data = s.data(using:.utf8)!
```

And now, the Really Amazing Part:

```
let locations = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Array<LocationModel>.self, from: data)
```

That's all!

Comment: Also I suggest you learn Swift 4, where this entire operation is trivial and most of your code can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks I found a way to see the code before it goes into my object class I think its the way ive been printing it override var description: String {
        return "Name: \(name), Address: \(address), Latitude: \(latitude), Longitude: \(longitude), id: \(id), Info: \(info), time: \(time)"

    }

Comment: Full ack. `Codable` is brilliant :-)

Comment: @JacobWebb No, it has nothing to do with how you were printing it. Read my answer. Read it carefully. Think about it.

Comment: @vadian go ahead and show how to do it with Codable. I yield the floor to you! :)

Comment: Hey thanks Matt its printing now one thing I am still confused on is it still says optional() -- output log below 

Name: Optional("test1"), Address: Optional("2206 ne parvin rd"), Latitude: Optional("39.172196"), Longitude: Optional("-94.549035"), id: Optional(1), Info: Optional("Special Going On"), time: Optional(1)
Name: Optional("test2"), Address: Optional("somewhere"), Latitude: Optional("39.171816"), Longitude: Optional("-94.548157"), id: Optional(2), Info: Optional("Special INN Deal"), time: Optional(2)

Comment: @matt No, thank you, the OP is encouraged to watch the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/) where everything is described in detail.

Comment: @JacobWebb I don't see what's confusing about that. You've typed these as `String?` etc., which means Optional. Maybe you should _learn_ Swift before trying to use it.